# Топология "Шина" в Ethernet

Tags: ethernet

Хотел спросить о данной топологии, когда все компьютеры объединены одним проводом, то по какой системе они отправляли кадры или пакеты друг-другу? Я знаю, что терминал (или компьютер) отправлял кадр с Mac-адресом, но как он узнавал, что в сети есть компьютер с таким-то Mac-адресом? И были ли в этой топологии, когда не было еще свичеров, хабов, роутеров и пр, Ip-адреса? Сокеты? Если компьютер передает к компьютеру по Mac-адресу, то нужны ли в компьютерах этой топологии Сокеты?

Comment: Сокеты это прикладной уровень, и он по сути не зависит от физической среды, т.е. для ОС по сути без разницы что у вас за сетевой интерфейс, 10BASE2/10BASE5 или 1GbE

Comment: Полноценный рассказ будет длинноват. Если вкратце (ответы в случайном порядке), то 1) сокеты и IP адреса были; 2) MAC в ethernet передается и сейчас; 3) для получения неизвестного MAC-адреса и тогда и сейчас применяется arp-протокол, в основе которого лежит broadcast запрос; 4) Передача осуществляется, когда среда (провод) свободна. При попытке одновременной передачи возникает коллизия, которая распознается во время передачи преамбулы обеими участниками. Коллизия разрешается взаимным засыпанием на случайное время.